# F-Spot: Can't view my photos anymore after update to Quantal

Tags: 12.10, f-spot

I upgraded to Quantal a few days ago. After that I could not view my photos anymore in F-Spot. I can only see the tags and the image data but not the images or their thumbs. The photo-db seems to be okay, it has been updated (automatically?) to sqlite3, and I can open the pictures with F-Spot viewer, GIMP, EOG or any other program - but not in F-Spot itself.

I hope there is an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is this caused by the new mount point of external usb devices - not directly in `/media`, but in `/media/<yourName>`?